# ERROR: Could not determine the startup mode

Tags: hbase

I installed hbase-2.4.8 on my windows pc and I have tried starting up the hbase.cmd and I keep getting this error message: ERROR: Could not determine the startup mode. It displays this message
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/slf4j/LoggerFactory... and this
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.slf4j.LoggerFactory...

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ran into the same problem, albeit in version 2.4.9. It's because the necessary JAR files can't be located when the script is executed. I solved it by adding the appropriate path (`<hbase_root_dir>\lib\client-facing-thirdparty`, under which you will find the necessary JARs) to classpath in `<hbase_root_dir>\conf\hbase-env.cmd`, like so:

`set HBASE_CLASSPATH=%HBASE_HOME%\lib\client-facing-thirdparty\*`

Comment: the asker wants some solving answer (not the next problem)